# PHP: How to get $ to print using echo

Tags: php, echo

I'm very new to PHP and having a hard time finding this answer as $ denotes a variable in PHP.
I'm trying to echo a total for items, such as:

```
echo "Your total is ${$total}";
```

The problems is the $ in front causes it to do nothing. I tried doing '$' but it prints the
' ' around the $. How do I get the $ to print in front of the variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use double quotes ("), you have to escape the $ character :

```
echo "Your total is \${$total}";
```

Answer (score 9):

Just use single quotes.

`echo 'Your total is $' . $total;`

Check this article for more information regarding the differences between single and double quotes in PHP.

http://v1.jeroenmulder.com/weblog/2005/04/php_single_and_double_quotes.php

Comment: Don't forget to number_format($total, 2); so things like 1250.5 will display as 1,250.50

Comment: If using `echo`, it's actually quicker to pass parameters than perform concatenation, eg `echo 'Your total is $', $total;`

Answer (score 7):

Last but not least:

```
printf('Your total is $%.2f', $total);
```

Comment: +1 for printf. Seems like people are forgetting how to do it the c way ;)

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the dollar sign: `echo "\$";`.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Your total is $" . $total;
```

You don't have to use variable parsing in every possible situation. Very often it is much easier (both to write and to understand) when simply writing as a string concatenation..

Comment: I thought the same thing when I was a beginner (not implying you are), but after a few thousand lines, I realised that the syntax with brackets ({}) is really fun and clear to use. It's a little bit slower than concatenation, but not in a significant way. It's a pretty subjective topic though!