# Unable to print $ in php

Tags: php, echo

This has a lot of answers on other pages of stackoverflow, [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473876/how-to-print-with-php) however none of them seem to work for me.
I've this small piece of code as:

```
echo $optionss='$'."q_option".$de;
```

In above code, i have a few variables by the name of `"q_option0"`, `"q_option1"`, `"q_option2"`... up to `"q_option4"`. `$de` is a variable that holds count from 0-4.

Now i want to print `$optionss= $q_option0` (this is in a for loop to get the increment of last number upto 4), but i'm unable to do so!
Please suggest me what i'm doing wrong!!

Comment: Can you show the output you expect with the echo statement. is it a string that contains "$q_option0" or is it the contents of a variable named `$q_option0`

Answer (score 0):

I Think you dint process the array $de. you can use foreach or for loop .Try this .

```
<?php
$de=array(1,2,3,4);
foreach($de as $val){
echo $optionss='$'."q_option".$val."<br>";  
}
?>
```

or  use single quotes as given

```
<?php
$de=array(1,2,3,4);
foreach($de as $val){
echo $optionss='$q_option'.$val."<br>"; 
}
?>
```

or  try this

```
<?php
$dollar="$";
$de=array(1,2,3,4);
foreach($de as $val){
echo $optionss=$dollar.'q_option'.$val."<br>";  
}
?>
```

output

```
$q_option1
$q_option2
$q_option3
$q_option4
```

Comment: I did process the array earlier, and i also tried your code but it still is not working!! I get output as: q_option1, q_option2, q_option3, q_option4.

Comment: I already did, this is the output: q_option1, q_option2, q_option3, q_option4.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote to print special characters

'$q_option'.$de;

Also you have forgotten to place $optionss within single quotes if you do not want its value printed out.

```
echo '$optionss= $q_option'.$de; // print the whole expression
```

But if you do this..

```
echo $optionss='$'."q_option".$val."<br>"; // assign right hand side of the expression to the variable '$optionss' and print that out
    // so you will only get output $q_option0, $q_option1... instead of $optionss=$q_option0, $optionss=$q_option1....
```

Below is solution to a different problem as I misunderstood it:

I assume its to dynamically create variable names and read their values

you can either create a temporary variable with the value as the name of the variable you want to access and then use double $$ to access the value of the variable inside the variable. Make sense?

```
$tmp = "q_option".$de;
echo $optionss=$$tmp;
```

Comment: Well IMHO, this is something i think should not work because we cannot associate a $$ with a variable name. What i got output from your code is this: Array

Comment: Put optionss= inside single quotes other wise you get its value printed and nothing if its not assigned a value. echo '$optionss= $q_option'.$de;

Answer (score 0):

If "q_option0", "q_option1", "q_option2" etc are variables, then you reference the value of these varaibles with `$$`. This will output "abc". Note that the variable `$optionss` is being assigned the value of the variable `$q_option0` in this code at the same time as its value is being echoed.

```
$de = 0;
$q_option0 = "abc";

$var = "q_option".$de;
echo $optionss = $$var;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the doller symbol '$'and use double $$ to access the value of the variable.

Assume `$q_option0 = "400";` 
Try This :

```
<?php
$q_option0 = "400"; 
$de = 0;

$optionss="q_option".$de;
echo "Your Output: " . $$optionss;
```

Output :

```
Your Output: 400
```